# admob + fb AN в app android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Можно использовать сразу Admob и facebook audience network в приложении android? Если да, то как? Потому что у меня выдает ошибку. Я не могу одновременно подключить `import com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd;` и `import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;` Спасибо!)

Comment: если суть вопроса - как использовать классы с одинаковыми именами - один нужно импортировать, а со вторым везде полное имя писать (com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd вместо просто InterstitialAd).

Comment: @Maxgmer Спасибо, помогло!)